# How do I write a Postgres SQL command based on metadata of the tables themselves?

Tags: postgresql, metadata

I want to retrieve all the records that were modified in the past hour of running the command. It is purely a meta data command (with no regard to the content of any tabular column data). I want to identify tables and rows of those tables that had some DML modification with a specified temporal duration.

Does Postgres need special configuration to track such detailed meta data before I run a command to return the info I am looking for?

What query would I run to get the results I am looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Postgres **9.5** introduced a feature to record commit timestamps. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP)

> `track_commit_timestamp` (`bool`)
>
> Record commit time of transactions. This parameter can only be set in
> `postgresql.conf` file or on the server command line. The default value
> is `off`.

[Some functions to work with it were added, too.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP)

Once the **DB server is restarted** with this setting activated, Postgres tracks commit timestamps. Then, for example, to get all rows from a table that were changed in any way during the last 4 hours:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin) >= now() - interval '4 hours';
```

Related:

- [How list all tables with data changes in the last 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512888/939860)
- [Atomically set SERIAL value when committing transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944402/939860)