# Is there way to get transaction commit timestamp in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have data-pulling functionality that once in 5 seconds grabs all the data from Postgres table basing on **modified_timestamp** column. It works the following way:

1. `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE modified_timestamp > _some_persisted_timestamp`
2. _some_persisted_timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
3. Processing data received from *step 1*
4. Sleep for 5s
5. Go to *step 1*

Where **modified_timestamp** updated with trigger (after any row update **modified_timestamp** becomes `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).
It worked fine until I noticed that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in Postgres is transaction start timestamp in fact and some of the updates are lost. Why are they lost? That's quite simple - at the moment when I execute query `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE modified_timestamp > _some_persisted_timestamp` some of the changes have already occurred, but **modified_timestamp** is before updated **_some_persisted_timestamp** because transaction is in progress still.

This problem could be easily solved by assigning in *step 2* **timestamp when update becomes visible for other transactions** (transaction commit timestamp in other words) instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or clock_timestamp().

I read documentation, but have found nothing related to transaction commit timestamp. Could you kindly suggest smth?

Btw, I'm aware of [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/logicaldecoding.html) and I know that this mechanism suits better for my needs in theory, but there are certain practical problems not allowing me to use it.

Comment: You are linking to the Postgres 9.4 manual. Doesn't mean you are on 9.4, does it? (Would be a dealbreaker.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm on 9.5.4 and can update if required version is available in Amazon RDS

Comment: Upgrade at least to the latest point release. 9.5.16 at the time of writing. See recommendations [here](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This problem could be easily solved by assigning in step 2 timestamp
> when update becomes visible for other transactions (transaction commit
> timestamp in other words) instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or
> clock_timestamp().

This is logically impossible. Postgres writes new row versions *before* it finally commits to make them visible. It would require prophetic capabilities to write a future timestamp yet unknown at the time of writing.

**However**, you can get commit timestamps from a different source: since Postgres 9.5, there is a GUC setting **[`track_commit_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP)** to start logging commit timestamps globally.

Then you can get commit timestamps with the utility function [`pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xid)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP). Your query could look like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t
WHERE   pg_xact_commit_timestamp(t.xmin) > _some_persisted_timestamp;
```

Be aware that commit timestamps are not kept around forever. [After
two billion transactions transactions (2^31), transaction IDs are "frozen".](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) That does not delete it right away, but after 4 billion transactions, the information is gone for certain. That's a big number of transactions, and only very busy databases burn that much over a lifetime. But there can be programming errors burning through transaction numbers more quickly than expected ...

Your *step 2* and *step 3* trade positions, and you record the commit timestamp instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - or `xmin` from any freshly updated row to derive the commit timestamp with `pg_xact_commit_timestamp()` once more.

More:

- [How do I write a Postgres SQL command based on metadata of the tables themselves?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159189/how-do-i-write-a-postgres-sql-command-based-on-metadata-of-the-tables-themselves/159221#159221)
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#Commit_timestamp_tracking

About `xmin`:

- [How to view tuples changed in a PostgreSQL transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123145/how-to-view-tuples-changed-in-a-postgresql-transaction/123183#123183)

But I am not completely sure I understand your task. Maybe you need a queuing tool or process rows one by one like discussed here:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed response! To understand more about my task: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html
Problem occurs while using timestamp mode - connector works exactly the same way as I described in question. And it loses updates.
Solution you suggested looks awesome - need to test it first before accepting as right answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/a/56961372/5320906

Comment: Is `t.xmin` only generated when `track_commit_timestamp` is enabled?

Comment: @RonJohn: No, `xmin` is a system column that's part of the tuple header and always there for any regular, unlogged, or temp table. But transaction timestamps are only recorded after `track_commit_timestamp` is turned on.