# Finding timestamp when index was created or reindexed

Tags: postgresql, index, metadata, change-tracking

Is there any way to find when an index was last created or reindexed in PostgreSQL 12-13?

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/monitoring-stats.html) show a few standard views like `pg_stat_user_indexes` that track usage statistics for indexes, but I can't find anything that tracks creation/update statistics.

Answer (score 5):

Creating the index, as well as re-indexing, writes a new row to the system table `pg_class`. Most DDL commands (including these) are transactional in Postgres. When the Postgres DB server runs with [**`track_commit_timestamp = on`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP), commit timestamps are recorded. See:

- [How do I write a Postgres SQL command based on metadata of the tables themselves?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159189/how-do-i-write-a-postgres-sql-command-based-on-metadata-of-the-tables-themselves/159221#159221)

Then, this query produces the timestamp when the index was last created or reindexed in Postgres 9.5 or later:

```
SELECT pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin)
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  relname = 'mytbl_pkey';  -- index name
```

Tracking only starts *after* the server is restarted with `track_commit_timestamp = on`, there is no information for older transactions. And the information is not kept indefinitely - it's lost eventually as transaction IDs wrap around, typically after a very long time, but that depends on transactions per time.